# Dynamic turtle creation in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo and was hoping if someone can help me with how to create turtles based on the user input.

In the interface tab i have a slider whose value ranges between 2 & 10. Depending on the value defined by the user using this slider, that many number of turtles should be created.

I tried using multiple if statements but there is a problem in the succeeding steps.

```
if (slider-value = 2) [create2]
if (slider-value = 3) [create3]
if (slider-value = 4) [create4]
if (slider-value = 5) [create5]
```

After creating the turtles using the above if conditions, i have to assign some rules to each individual turtle, and i tried again using multiple if statements. But it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone suggest a way, would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: What to your create procedures look like?

Comment: okay are you still stuck on the assigning rules bit?

Comment: I tried what Seth-Tisue had suggested below initially but in my case each of the individual turtle created has its own co-ordinate positions. Hence depending on the number of turtles created i have to assign a position to them.

Comment: Please update your question to also describe the coordinates issue. Could you also provide some examples (eg what coordinates do you want for 2, and what coordinates for 10 turtles?)

Comment: For some reason i was unable to add my code, so i have created a new question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710775/dynamic-turtle-creation-in-netlogo-2-contd)

Answer (score 3):

You could more simply use the slider thus

```
create-turtles slider-value [
                 ;things you want the turtles to do for example
                 set heading 4 * random 90 
                 set shape "turtle"
                 set color green + random-normal 0 4
                 ]
```

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Seth Tisue
Thanks for the reply but in my case each turtle that is to be created has its own co-ordinate position. The following code might give you an idea:

Comment: could you add that to your question or make a new question the fomatting make it hard to read.

Comment: For some reason i was unable to add my code, so i have created a new question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710775/dynamic-turtle-creation-in-netlogo-2-contd)

Answer (score -4):

I recommend a switch statement.
A switch statement cycles through all your possible commands ,typically with an int. And then selects the match command.

So for example I could make a switch statement that when user inputs the up arrow. the int 1 is the input. this is matched to a command that tells the turtle to move up so many pixels/units/cubes.

I hope that helps.

Comment: NetLogo does not have `switch` or `case` statements. It does, however, have a "create <however many>" type statement (`create-turtles n`) which is what the other answer proposes. Please don't suggest answers for languages you have clearly never seen, it is very unhelpful because new answers go to the top.

Comment: 'I tried using multiple if statements but there is a problem in the succeeding steps'
I gave a suggestion based on this , the implementation of a switch statement wasn't asked, of which netlogo can achieve.